# How can I use an Ant foreach iteration with values from a file?

Tags: ant, foreach, build.xml, ant-contrib

In our [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build environment, I have to do the same task for a number of items. The [AntContrib foreach task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) is useful for that. However, the list is in a parameter, where I actually have the list in a file. How can I iterate over items in a file in an foreach-like way in Ant? Something like (pseudo-code):

```
<foreach target="compile-module" listFromFile="$fileWithModules"/>
```

I'm happy to write a custom Task, and welcome any suggestion on possible solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to load the file into a property and iterate over it, worked fine for me:

```
<loadfile property="file-content" srcFile="${fileWithModules}"/>

<foreach
    target="compile-module"
    list="${file-content}"
    delimiter="${line.separator}"
    param="your-param-used-in-target"/>
```