# How do I execute an ant task for each line in a given file?

Tags: ant

I need to execute an ant task for each line from a given file. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "each line from a given file" ?

Comment: Sure, assume a file like:

param1 param2 param3
param4 param5 param6
...

I would like ant to read that file and pass the parameters to a subtask.

Answer (score 2):

I have a properties file that defines processes that need to be run. This is all on a single line and comma separated, not multiple lines as you have specified. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757090/how-can-i-use-an-ant-foreach-iteration-with-values-from-a-file) shows how to iterate over a file.

```
env.start=webserver:localhost, dataserver:localhost
```

then in my ant file that handles application execution I have the following

```
<target name="start-all" description="Start all processes specified in target-info.properties:env.start">
        <foreach list="${env.start}" trim="yes" param="process.and.host" target="-start-process"/>
</target>

<target name="-start-process">
        <property name="colon.separated.pattern" value="([^:]*):([^:]*)"/>
        <propertyregex property="process" input="${process.and.host}" regexp="${colon.separated.pattern}" select="\1"/>
        <propertyregex property="host" input="${process.and.host}" regexp="${colon.separated.pattern}" select="\2"/>
        <condition property="start.target" value="start-${process}" else="-start-process-ssh">
            <equals arg1="${host}" arg2="localhost" trim="yes" casesensitive="no"/>
        </condition>
        <antcall target="${start.target}"/>
</target>
```

${start.target} then is executed for the processes defined in the env.start property for example

```
<target name="start-webserver" description="Start the webserver on this machine">
        <echo>** Starting webserver **</echo>
        <run-script dir="${project.base.dir}/apache-tomcat" script="${project.base.dir}/apache-tomcat/bin/startup" spawn="yes">
            <args>
                <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${project.base.dir}/apache-tomcat"/>
                <env key="CATALINA_PID" value="${project.base.dir}/apache-tomcat/logs/pid_catalina"/>
            </args>
        </run-script>
</target>

<target name="start-dataserver" depends="decipher_caldb_password,check-event-seed,run-prestart-sql" description="Start the dataserver on this machine">
        <run-calypso process="dataserver" class="calypsox.apps.startup.StartNOGUI" failonerror="yes"
            args="-class com.calypso.apps.startup.StartDataServer"/>
</target>
```

I can start all the processes defined in env.start by running

```
ant -f run.xml start-all
```